# transparency in swf in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, flash

how can i control swf background transparency in vb.net.........either with flash.ocx or if there is any other way.......so that if i have a swf animation block with red in background and some text written with yellow.......now how can i remove that red background in vb.net...actually i want to make a system so that i can choose any color as transparency key for swf.........like in tv channels logos.......etc

Comment: Way... too... many... elipses...

Also rather... difficult.... to understand... the question.... etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you simply cannot.
The Flash file will always play over everything else, and is ignorant (more or less) of things outside of it.

It is the nature of having such a rigidly seperated third party content format and player.

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news :(

Comment: but i only want to set a transparency key for background of swf move...not the whole object...

Comment: You can make a Flash object have transparency to the background of the .swf, but not transparent to your VB.NET application.

Comment: am just making a video player with ability to place a swf logo on it....now if i simply include that swf logo file it shows its original background...while i want to show only content not the background....

Answer (score 1):

If your swf truly has a transparent background and you're playing it over a solid-colored surface you can set the container AxShowwaveFlash's `BGColor` to be the same as the background. For instance, if you've got a swf called `AxShockwaveFlash1` playing on top of a standard VB.Net form you can use this code:

```
Me.AxShockwaveFlash1.BGColor = Me.BackColor.R.ToString("X2") & Me.BackColor.G.ToString("X2") & Me.BackColor.B.ToString("X2")
```

Comment: your code helped. I created a round circle and it has edges all round of it with your code. is it possible to make it smooth round circle?

Answer (score 0):

Set the property BGColor 0f your Shockwave flash object to "F0F0F0"

example:
your Shockwave flash object name is AxShockwaveFlash1

```
AxShockwaveFlash1.BGColor="F0F0F0"
```